# Ubuntu datetime locale on login screen

Tags: gnome, login-screen, locale

I've installed Ubuntu 19.10, language/locale/formats are set in US/en. And everything seems to work OK, except datetime language on login screen (when I turn on my laptop and see fields for user/password logging). It has local-language-style. 
So, datetime language for user / lockscreen picks up correctly, but for login screen - nope. What's the reason and how can I fix this ?

Output of `locale` command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to System Settings -> Region & Languages -> Manage Installed Languages.

Then you can choose your things and then select Apply System Wide..

Read the text under "Apply System-Wide" Tab. Which is

`Use the same language choices for startup and the login screen.` when you are in "Language" Section.

and

`Use the same format choice for startup and the login screen.` when you are in "Regional Formats" Section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would call it 'hidden functionality' :)