# Cannot set language and format of login screen

Tags: gnome, 20.04, login-screen

I want to set the language and format of the login screen to English (United Kingdom). It appears to work: if I click the Login Screen button in the Settings dialog, set the language/format, dismiss the dialog and open it again, it seems that the language and format are saved:

[image]

However, when I log out, it reverts to English (United States) on the login screen. For example, I can see that the date on the login screen is shown in US format (Jul 31) instead of UK format (31 Jul). How can I make it permanently switch to UK?

Comment: Can u try this https://askubuntu.com/q/1222879/739431

Comment: @PRATAP sorry, even after clicking "Apply system-wide" it still defaults to EN-US on the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok..I have tested this with English US as main language and English UK as login screen's

The settings did not persist until I added the English UK Input Source for Login Settings. Once added I deleted English US Input Source from Login Settings.. you may choose if you wish to keep it or not.

Here are pics which are self expletive

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did the same - English UK is the _only_ language listed in input settings but unfortunately the display on the login screen is still in US format. Glad it worked for you though. +1 in appreciation of your perseverance.